# wireless mobile cable?

Tags: wireless, cable, adapter

I'm looking for a way to connect a mobile device to a generic computer device wireless.

Simply converting the normal micro usb / type c / lightning cable into a wireless micro usb / type c / lightning cable accordingly.

there shell be 2 dongles:

one USB type A which will be plugged to the PC / car, it will soak power from the PC, and transfer every I/O data from the USB to some 2.4GHz channel

the second one will have micro USB / type c / lightning port interface and operates the same.

and these devices will simulate being plugged by wire while actually the phone and the PC device aren't attached.

Visual motivative illustration:
[image]

In the above picture, theres comparison between old normal way (above) of connecting phone to a PC device using normal cable, just plugin each one and they communicate through the cable vs the new way (below) using two dongles, who simulate **the same functionality** but over the air.

Is there such a device out there in the market?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to understand. Are you looking for a wireless USB connection? If yes, I would edit accordingly

Comment: what's up with the negative feedback?! I've added a visual illustration.. hope now you'll understand...

Comment: I think the feedback is just because it's expressed using unusual words. The sketch makes it clear. This definitely seems to exist, try e.g. looking for `wireless USB connection` on Amazon

Comment: Thanks,  better results are replying to the query of `wireless usb extender`, although I couldn't fetch any product that looks modern enough to be small as I imagined such as todays wireless mouse's ultra tiny dongles.

Answer (score 1):

So I found this on the search
https://huddlecamhd.com/usb2air/

Which pretty much do what I asked for..

Unfortunately its only for windows and very bulky so a better answer is still appreciated.